# Is it possible to use backtrace in hook using LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c, hook, backtrace, ld-preload

I have a compiled binary, and I want to use a hook through `LD_PRELOAD`.
The hook can print the specific function name once it is called.
However, I can't determine when the function is called, and what is its caller.
As a result, I copied the `print_trace` function from the official example(https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_node/libc_653.html) into my hook. Sadly, I can only get `Obtained 0 stack frames`. Am I wrong or this is just not possible?

[EDIT]
The following is the code of hook. In this example, I print all `popen` when it is called. Also, I want to print the backtrace info, but this does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

typedef FILE *(*popen_t)(const char *command, const char *type);

void print_trace(void)
{
    void *array[10];
    size_t size;
    char **strings;
    size_t i;

    size = backtrace(array, 10);
    strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);
    if (NULL == strings)
    {
        perror("backtrace_symbols");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Obtained %zd stack frames.\n", size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);

    free(strings);
    strings = NULL;
}

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type){
    static popen_t orig_popen=NULL;
    orig_popen = (popen_t) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "popen");
    printf("popen(%s,%s)\n",command,  type);
    print_trace();
    return orig_popen(command,  type);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.  Are you using [`RTLD_NEXT`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) with `dlsym`?

Comment: Yes, I am using `dlsym`, so this is the  reason?

Comment: @desionxxx which platform are you using ?? Your issue could not be seen in my linux

Comment: @nhatnq I am using qemu to run it under an arm environment. And, yes, the problem is that `backtrace`  is not work under arm directly.